# Сделать go get репозитория без обновления его внутренних зависимостей

Tags: golang, зависимости, mod, dependencyproperty

Когда я делаю `go get` нужного мне репозитория (моего отдельного репозитория), вместо того чтобы просто подтянуть все зависимости, он обновляет версии некотрых внутренних зависимостей того репозитория, который я стягиваю, и скачивает их. Такими тэмпами, однажды это сломает сборку.

Как я могу сделать `go get` репозитория, без обновления его внутренних звисимотей? Или, возможно, там есть внутренний механизм, который предотвратит обновление и скачивание обратно несовместимых версий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом примере главный модуль зависит от A 1.0 и B 2.1.
Поскольку B 2.1 зависит от A 1.1, будет использоваться именно эта версия A.
и еще используется A 1.1, а он в свою очередь использует C 1.1.

Окончательный список зависимостей:
A 1.1 
B 2.1 
C 1.1

теперь понимаете почему `go get` или `go mod tidy` обновляют ненужные вам зависимости?
вы можете попробоввать использовать exclude или replace

```
require (
    github.com/dep/one v1.0.0
    github.com/dep/two/v2 v2.3.0
    github.com/dep/other v0.0.0-20180523231146-b3f5c0f6e5f1
    github.com/dep/legacy v2.0.0+incompatible
)

exclude github.com/dep/legacy v1.9.2
replace github.com/dep/one => github.com/fork/one
```

exclude - запрещает использование определенной версии модуля
replace - заменяет один модуль на другой

Comment: Вопрос, если появится С1.2, представим, что репо C обновилась; и я использую в main module комманду go get для B2.1 или пропишу там же go mod tidy. Он обновит пакет С до 1.2 или нет?

Comment: нет, не обновит, потому что ни одна из зависимостей не ссылается до C1.2. надо чтобы хоть кто-то ссылался

Comment: А разве репа А в этом случае не захочет обновить С зависимсоть с 1.1 до 1.2?

Comment: нет. с чего бы? репа A 1.1 четко ссылается на конкретную версию.

Comment: Благодарю от всего сердца, что разъяснили, как это работает!

Answer (score 0):

Ну для начала **не используй** `go get` используй `go mod`, тогда все зависимости с версиями будут явно храниться в журнале `go.mod`.

```
go mod init .
go mod edit -require github.com/wilk/uuid@0.0.1
go get -v -t ./...
go build
go install
```

Comment: Мне приходится использовать go get, так как мне нужно обновить только одну зависимость, остальные мне обновлять не нужно.

Comment: Совсем не нужно всё обновлять. Это просто как пример. go mod решает 99.9% всех проблем с зависимостями и их корректными версиями.

Comment: Хорошо, но все же я не понимаю, как мне обновить только одну зависимость в mod файле. Если, более точно, как мне обновить одну зависимость до последней версии (тэга). Наверное, можно прописать latest в mod файле, но если есть другой вариант, я бы выбрал его.